# What can we conclude from $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=f(xy)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x + y) + f(x − y) = f(xy)$ for all $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is:
>
> A. Strictly increasing.
>
> B. Strictly decreasing.
>
> C. Identically zero.
>
> D. Constant but not necessarily zero.

I have no idea how to do this. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Try some specific $x$ and $y$, see what you can conclude.

Comment: On a multiple choice test, we see that C works, so A and B are wrong.  Then assuming D, we get $c+c=c\implies c=0$ so the correct answer is C.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your input :-)

Answer (score 9):

The case $y=0$ gives $2f(x)=f(0)$, implying C.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** First set $x=y=0$. Then set just $y=0$.

Comment: By taking $x=y=0$ in given condition, we get $2f(0)=f(0)$ that imply $f(0)=0$. Now by taking $y=0$ in given condition we get $2f(x)=f(0)$. Hence we have $2f(x)=0$. Hence $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint sir.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Check $y=0$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$